# Dependent unit tests and returning Task<T> from a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

How does MSTest framework handle unit tests that are dependent upon other unit tests? I'm testing a REST API and have spent quite some time trying to understand the big picture. The following questions came up during this journey:

1. Should we write test methods that call other test methods? Is it somehow against the idea of *unit* testing? Or should unit tests be completely isolated from each other?
2. If isolated, what do we do when certain api endpoint requires input that can only be fetched by calling another API endpoint (for which a test already exists)? For example, the endpoint `GetMembers` endpoint requires authentication token which can only be obtained by calling `Login` endpoint. A separate test exists for each endpoint. Is it fair to call `TestLogin` method from `TestGetMembers`, or should I repeat the entire code of `TestLogin` inside `TestGetMembers` (or write a function to share code for that matter)?
3. Where should I keep the login token since it will be required by all subsequent tests. It looks like MSTest creates a new instance of the test class for each test method, so my global variables get lost. Is it okay to declare `static` variables to hold such values?
4. What about `async` tests? My research shows that an `async` test can return `Task` but not `Task<T>`. Visual Studio Test Explorer does not list any test methods that return `Task<T>` and trying to run them manually (e.g. by right-clicking inside the method and choosing `Run Test`) finishes without actually running the test method. Is there such a limitation? If yes, how can I return value from a async test method that will be consumed by another test method?

Comment: Are you testing controller methods which represent endpoints?

Comment: @ElConrado: I'm testing all the endpoints exposed by the web api. This is basically a test of all functions of my data service (one service method per endpoint).

Comment: Sounds more like an integration-test then.

Comment: @rene: which is not what mstest framework is supposed to handle?

Comment: That is not a problem but readers of this question might jump into "unit test think" offering all kind of well meant but not always applicable advice in an "integration test" scenario. The tool doesn't matter, the objective does.

Comment: Testcode (unit or integration) follow the same rules as regular code. If you follow the Arrange, Act, Assert philosophy in your single test method, you wouldn't copy/paste code but instead refactor (extract method, move to base class, etc).

Comment: There are decorated methods for Per test setup/teardown and per class setup/teardown where "global" state can go, like login. Not static, just instance vars on your Test class.

Comment: @rene: That thing (`ClassInitialize`, `Teardown`) I have already tried and it kind of works (only through `static` globals, instance globals get lost since mstest creates new instances of test class for each test method). However the global variable space is getting more and more polluted since I now have to keep the returned results of each unit test for the consumption of dependent unit tests. But I think this might be the closest we can get with it.

Comment: How-to do unit testing for external API (like Fake API ) api.chucknorris.io ? 
 
 **[simple-example-of-calling-rest-api-with-httpclient-in-net5.0](https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/simple-example-of-calling-rest-api-with-httpclient-in-net5.0)**

Answer (score 0):

I answer mostly for your first question. If you are able to mock server behaviour you can test endpoint methods but in my opinion it is over engineering. Unit tests are designed for testing unit logic. In good design you inject logic to controllers (for example as a service, facade, or other architectural object) and you need to test methods which are injected. As in the code below I don’t test the GetById controller method, I test _facade.MyMethod(). If you have more complicated logic in your controller methods, you should move it to another layer. If you will test facade logic, as I write in example, you can omit authentication, because you don’t need a token, although it also depends on your authorization mechanism.

```
public class MyExampleObjectController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IExampleObjectFacade _facade;

    public MyExampleObjectController(IExampleObjectFacade facade)
    {
        _facade = facade;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    [ProducesResponseType(404)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(Guid id,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var item = await _facade.MyMethod(id, cancellationToken);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to understand. My data service is a very thin layer that simply calls the api endpoints using RestSharp, de-serializes returned data and returns it to caller. So there is a `Login` function in my data service that calls `/login` endpoint, a `GetMembers` function that calls `/members` endpoint and so on. Now my unit tests are testing each of these functions (one test per function), but some tests depend upon other tests. e.g. `GetMemberDetails` needs member id, which can only be fetched by calling `GetMembers`, so that's where the confusion begins.

Comment: Ok, so your problem is correlated with using releated data. This data is downloaded through API enpoints by your service. In this case, I suggest to mock internal enpoint, so your unit test calls /login but receive mock data. Are you considering to use Moq?

Comment: mmm... I have heard about Moq and probably understand what it does, but the tests are supposed to check the service itself (and thereby the live api endpoints), not some mock. Idea is to simply run all tests in my class to make sure that the service can correctly process data returned by the live server and feed the higher layers.

Comment: Does the data from live api endpoints can change your test result?

Comment: Yes, if there is some server-side change, such as api parameters or return types, since I'm not in control of the server side. These tests are simply a means of providing me a one-click solution to quickly figure out if all endpoints are accepting and returning expected stuff.

Comment: I understand, but in my opinion it isn't unit test, because you want to test your whole layer logic. Moreover, your test depends on server-side changes, although unit test should depends only on implementation.

Comment: I see what u mean and perhaps agree too. Thank you for your input. Much appreciated.